# Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value:

Tags: angular-material, material-design, angular7

How to avoid getting this console error.

ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'bg-fade: false'. Current value: 'bg-fade: true'.

I am trying to add a class to the mat-sidenav-container based on the truth value, whenever the value changes am getting the mentioned error.

app.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-container [ngClass]="{'bg-fade': showSpinner}">
```

app.component.ts

```
showSpinner: boolean;

constructor(private httpStatus: HTTPStatus) {
    this.httpStatus.getHttpStatus()
      .subscribe((status: boolean) => {
        this.showSpinner = status;
      });
  }
```

styles.css

```
.bg-fade {
    opacity: 0.3 !important;
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.httpStatus.getHttpStatus().subscribe((status: boolean) => {
        this.showSpinner = status;
    });
}, 200);
```

Comment: No, setTimeout didn't work, i got the same error in console again.